# Write to SMS inbox

Tags: java, android, permissions, sms

Hi iam creating a fake sms application, i want to write a sms message to inbox..

I got all the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

**Method**

```
 public void SendSmsMessage(View v){

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("address", "111111");
        values.put("body", "hello amma");
        values.put("read", "0"); 
        values.put("date", "");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Uri  uri = Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI;
            context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
        } else {
            context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
        }

    }
```

When i execute the method it is not saving the message to sms inbox. by the way i am not getting any error message also. can someone help me to fix this tnx..

Comment: Since KitKat (4.4, API level 19), your app cannot write to the SMS Provider unless it is the current default messaging app. Attempts to do so by non-default apps will just fail, but won't throw an Exception (usually).

Comment: Are you testing on a device/emulator running KitKat or above?

Comment: kikat and above.. Mashmallow

Comment: Hy is there any other alternatives... to achieve this task..

Comment: Nope, not on Marshmallow. There's a security hole in 4.4 _only_ whereby a non-default can get write access, but they fixed it after that.

Comment: ok, i got it.. Thank you for the support. @Mike